# Extract small portion of image without loading all of it

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, imagemagick, jpeg

I have large JPG images ( say 20000x10000 pixels) and want to extract sub-images from these images without loading whole image.

I found it's possible by using this ImageMagick command:

```
convert -extract 226x248+4216+3377 a.jpg o.jpg
```

But I need to have it in my C# WPF app.

[Magick.NET](http://magick.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Magick.NET/MagickImage.h) did not implement extract methods.

Is there any .NET library for this? Or at least a simple exe that can be copied without installing big libs like ImageMagick on client machines.

Comment: Is extracting sub-images solution to a problem or the problem itself? If you need thumbnails (to example), then you can generate them at same time as you create large images. Or what is the purpose of sub-images?

Comment: Big images are not generated by me, I just import them into my app, and I need random crops after adding them.

Comment: How random crops are? What are they used for? What is the use of import process? What is your software doing with big images and with cropped? I am still thinking about sort of thumbnails (which are generated once and then used), and it could be absolutely ok to run trough **slow** and **memory consuming** import **once**, to generate them once (which means, load whole image, proceed as usual).

Answer (score 3):

Magick.NET does support extraction of a subimage. You should use the Crop method:

```
using(MagickImage image = new MagickImage("a.jpg"))
{
  image.Crop(new MagickGeometry(226,248,4216,3377));
  image.Write("o,jpg");
}
```

The -extract option of ImageMagick will read the whole jpg before cropping out the part you need. So maybe this is not a solution for your problem. Only for a small set of formats the image will not be read completely.

Comment: Does it load whole image a.jpg or just the portion it needs?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any c# libraries that can do this. Gdal at http://www.gdal.org can do it, though. It also has c# wrappers, might be a bit bulky just for this purpose, though.

Comment: As you mentioned it's too bulky, thanks.