# Random access to a huge image?

Tags: image, random, hdf5, random-access

I'm looking for a way to store a huge image in a way that allows random access to small regions without the need to load the whole image into memory. The focus is on speed and on a low memory footprint.

Let's say the image is 50k*50k 32-bit-pixels, amounting to ~9 GB (Currently it is stored as a single tiff file). One thing I found looks quite promising: [HDF5](http://hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) allows me to store and randomly access (integer) arrays of arbitrary size and dimension. I could put my image's pixels into such a database.

**What (other) (simpler?) methods for efficient random pixel access are out there?**

I would really like to store the image as a whole and avoid creating tiles for several reasons: The requested image region dimensions are not constant/predictable. I want to only load the pixels into memory that I really need. I would like to avoid the processing effort involved in tiling the image.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745780/random-access-image-picture-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract small portion of image without loading all of it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423502/extract-small-portion-of-image-without-loading-all-of-it)